# How to get a special character to render correctly in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have made amendments to this example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/3885304/

I am using data from the top 20 richest football clubs from the Deloitte Money league: https://www2.deloitte.com/uk/en/pages/press-releases/articles/deloitte-football-money-league-score-record-revenue.html

I have noticed that Athletico Madrid is coming up with an error.
Atl�tico de Madrid - this how it is rendered.

How can I correct that, please? The data that is being parsed to d3js is a .csv file that is being served by a local web server.

In the .csv file it looks correct like: Atlético de Madrid.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot export utf-8 encoded csv from ms excel. It is not a d3 issue, it's an excel issue. The best you can do is to use open or libre office, or to assemble the csv by hand.

Comment: Thakn you Tamas. What do you mean by 'assemble the csv by hand'? Get the data from the .csv file and have it as JSON or another format?

Comment: @AndyHitchings No, just open it with notepad and type in the info you want.

Comment: Hi Tamas, I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean? How can I get the Spanish character to render correctly? Also, does this issue not happen then with open or libre office .csv files?